# I want to change two edit text value on time picker selection

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have two edit text in my app and I want to call time picker on their focus and I am successful in calling time pickers on both the edittext but want to add different time on both the edit text filed.
I have start time edit text and end time edit text. I am mentioning my code.

```
public class AccessWeekDays extends Activity 
{
    String message_selectedWeekDay;
    TextView tvAdd;
    TextView tvEdit;
    TextView tvCurrentDay;

    EditText edSub;
    EditText edDesc;
    EditText edStartTime;
    EditText edEndTime;
    TimePicker timepicksubject;

    int phour;
    int pminute;
    Calendar calendar;

        //listenner for start time

                private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) 
                            {
                                /*Date d=new Date();
                                String myformat="hh:mm:a";
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myformat);
                                //String  formated_time = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
                                String  formated_time = sdf.format(d);*/
                                phour = hourOfDay;
                                pminute = minute;
                                updateDisplaystart();

                            }

                private void updateDisplaystart() 
                {

                    edStartTime.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(phour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(pminute)));

                }


                private String pad(int c) 
                {

                     if (c >= 10)
                            return String.valueOf(c);
                        else
                            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adding_timtable_part);

         calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

        tvAdd=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAdd);
        tvEdit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
        tvCurrentDay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCurentDay);


        edSub=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSubjectname);
        edDesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edDesc);
        edStartTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edStartTime);
        edEndTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edEndTime);

        timepicksubject=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickersubject);

        edSub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edStartTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edEndTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        message_selectedWeekDay=intent.getExtras().getString("selectedweekdays");

        setCurrentDay();


        tvAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tvAdd.setText("Done");
                tvEdit.setText("Cancel"); 

                edSub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edStartTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edEndTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });



        edStartTime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                showDialog(1);

            }
        });

        edEndTime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                showDialog(1);

            }
        });

    }//oncreate ends 


    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {
         switch (id) 
         {

                 case 1:

                     return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, phour, pminute,false);
                    // return new TimePickerDialog(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView)


                 default: 
                         break;
           }
                             return null;
        }
```

I am calling **updateDisplaystart()** method which writes the value of edit text and tell me how I can change the end time edit text value..

Comment: what is the difference between start time and end time

Comment: if u wanna find difference between two time or date..? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/ take a look..hope this link will help u

Comment: start time is time of start of event and end time is ending time of event

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this way:

Pass the `EditText` in `showDialog` method and use that for changing the `EditText` value.

Example:

```
    //your focus listener snippet
    edStartTime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            showDialog(1, edStartTime);

        }
    });

    edEndTime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            showDialog(1, edEndTime);

        }
    });

    //showDialog method should be changed to handle second argument of EditText
    public void showDialog(int id, EditText edText){
        //pass the EditText along with other arguments
    }
```

Now change the text in that EditText when your `onTimeSet` get called.